# Powershell - how to log all external cmd output?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that works great from cmd line, but flakes out a lot when running from task scheduler.

So I need to see all the console output from all the commands.

The script does a lot of external commands (net use, robocopy, etc). The output from these commands is what I most need.

We do not want to instrument each command, because it is ugly, and because we need to run it interactively (and see what is going on).

I tried the powershell "Start-Transcript" with -Verbose, but NONE of the commands are logged to the transcript file. Even when we followed [this directive](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2010/01/04/workaround-for-start-transcript-on-native-processes/) by a guy on the powershell team:  | Out-Default (e.g. ipconfig.exe | Out-Default), we STILL do not see the output in the transcript.

What next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure the logging to occur within the scheduled task via redirection of the powershell invocation:

```
cmd /c powershell.exe -noninteractive -file c:\temp\script.ps1 > c:\temp\some.log 2>&1
```

If the `ROBOCOPY` log is doing more than 10 files, I would keep that separate with the `/LOG:c:\temp\robo.log` option that command supports.

Comment: Hmmmm  From a cmd line , that works great. From a scheduled task, "c:\temp\some.log" is not created.  Maybe the params need quoting in a scheduled task?

Comment: Oops... see edit. Got to work if I wrapped ps invoke with cmd. lol

Answer (score 0):

Well, even if not the prettiest of solutions you could perhaps do something like the following?

```
net use z: \\my\path >> mylogfile.txt 2>&1
```

And you could do the same with the logging abilities of robocopy, just append to the same file.

Comment: No sale, sorry. OP enhanced.

Comment: Well, if PS 3.0 or higher you could try **robocopy.exe <more stuff> | Tee-Object -FilePath Mylog.txt -Append** or such...